# How to have multiple lines of intertext within align* environment?

Tags: spacing, align

So I have two sets of equations that I'd like to be aligned, but they're broken up by two lines of text, the second of which should be indented.

**MWE with Comments**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sbar}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\tsbar}[1]{\sbar{#1}^\sigma_s}
\begin{document}
For this first one, I can't figure out an appropriate width for the parbox and I can't figure out how to indent the second line of text (neither the indent command nor an hspace works).
\begin{align*}
        \tsbar{\phi x_1,\dots,v_k} &= T \text{ iff } \langle \sigma(v_1),\dots,\sigma(v_k) \rangle \in \sbar{\phi}_s;\\
        \tsbar{\lnot \phi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi} \neq T;\\
        \tsbar{\phi \rightarrow \psi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi}\neq T \text{ or } \tsbar{\psi}=T;\\
        \tsbar{\forall x \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } a\in D_s,\ \sbar{\phi}^{[v/a]} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_> \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t > s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_< \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t < s, \tsbar{\phi} = T.\\
\parbox{15em}{(Later-than is given the obvious definition: $t > s =_{df} s < t$.)\\[1ex]
%
\indent Then, the defined operators:}\\
        \tsbar{\Box_\geq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \geq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_\leq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s \vee s \leq t, \tsbar{\phi} = T.
\end{align*}
This one gives me everything I want, but yields a ``misplaced alignment character'' error that only disappears when I remove the double backslash before the second line in the intertext (and I haven't figured out how to produce the requisite spacing without it). 
\begin{align*}
        \tsbar{\phi x_1,\dots,v_k} &= T \text{ iff } \langle \sigma(v_1),\dots,\sigma(v_k) \rangle \in \sbar{\phi}_s;\\
        \tsbar{\lnot \phi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi} \neq T;\\
        \tsbar{\phi \rightarrow \psi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi}\neq T \text{ or } \tsbar{\psi}=T;\\
        \tsbar{\forall x \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } a\in D_s,\ \sbar{\phi}^{[v/a]} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_> \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t > s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_< \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t < s, \tsbar{\phi} = T.\\
\intertext{(The later-than relation on stages is given the obvious definition: $t > s =_{df} s < t$.)\\
%
Then, the defined operators:}
        \tsbar{\Box_\geq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \geq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_\leq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s \vee s \leq t, \tsbar{\phi} = T.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The desired formatting (the one produced by the second attempt in the MWE, the one with the alignment character error) is as follows:

[image]

How can I get this accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `\linewidth` for the width of the `\parbox`. There is a small catch: the macro called by `align` (or the *-variant thereof) doesn't accept `\par` inside it, so you can't use `\par` (or a blank line) for ending paragraphs in the `\longintertext` macro I suggest. A workaround is to use `\endgraf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sbar}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\newcommand{\tsbar}[1]{\sbar{#1}^\sigma_s}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\newcommand{\longintertext}[1]{%
  \intertext{%
    \parbox{\linewidth}{%
      \setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}
      \noindent#1%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

For this first one, I can't figure out an appropriate width for the parbox and I can't figure out how 
to indent the second line of text (neither the indent command nor an hspace works).
\begin{align*}
        \tsbar{\phi x_1,\dots,v_k} &= T \text{ iff } \langle \sigma(v_1),\dots,\sigma(v_k) \rangle \in \sbar{\phi}_s;\\
        \tsbar{\lnot \phi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi} \neq T;\\
        \tsbar{\phi \rightarrow \psi} &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi}\neq T \text{ or } \tsbar{\psi}=T;\\
        \tsbar{\forall x \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } a\in D_s,\ \sbar{\phi}^{[v/a]} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_> \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t > s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_< \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t < s, \tsbar{\phi} = T.\\
\longintertext{%
  (Later-than is given the obvious definition: $t > s =_{df} s < t$.)\endgraf
  Then, the defined operators:
}
        \tsbar{\Box_\geq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \geq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box_\leq \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
        \tsbar{\Box \phi} &= T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s \vee s \leq t, \tsbar{\phi} = T.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another great solution! Is there any practical difference between this and simply putting `\endgraf` after the first line in an `\intertext`?

Comment: `\intertext` uses `\vbox`, which doesn't do all the initializations performed by `\parbox`, so some unexpected results can show up. Perhaps `\linewidth` is better than `\displaywidth`, though. If you don't plan to use ``\\`` for other reasons, you can add ``\let\\=\par`` to the code, before `\noindent`, and use ``\\`` instead of `\endgraf`.

Comment: This eats `\footnote{...}`. Thoughts?

Comment: @imallett Use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetexr`

Comment: Thanks; `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext{...}` works. It also eats `\parskip`s. I tried doing what you did for `\parindent` for `\parskip` too but it yelled at me?

Comment: @imallett What's the purpose of nonzero `\parskip` other than making the document more difficult to read? And do you really want long text with several paragraphs in the middle of an alignment?

Comment: @egreg Nonzero `\parskip` is just a style. For example, it is (along with zero `\parindent`) a common journal style in my field (CS). I actually personally prefer it, finding it *more* readable, but nevermind. As to whether I want text with multiple paragraphs in the middle of an alignment, the answer is yes. The particular use-case is explaining the derivation of a formula: the formula's positioning shouldn't change when I move to the next line. "[S]everal paragraphs" of "long text" can still work out to only a couple cm on the page; the visual alignment is still relevant.

Answer (score 7):

You can use two possibilities:

- `\intertext{text... \endgraf text...}` (recommended)
- `\intertext{text... \smallskip\newline\hspace*{\parindent} text...}`

The accepted answer already shows the first possibility. Hence, I'll just show how the second possiblity looks like:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\sbar}{\lvert}{\rvert}
    \newcommand{\tsbar}[1]{\sbar{#1}^\sigma_s}
    
\begin{document}
    For this first one, I can't figure out an appropriate width for the parbox and I can't figure out how to indent the second line of text (neither the indent command nor an hspace works).
        \begin{align*}
    \tsbar{\phi x_1,\dots,v_k} 
        &= T \text{ iff } \langle \sigma(v_1),\dots,\sigma(v_k) \rangle \in \sbar{\phi}_s;\\
    \tsbar{\lnot \phi} 
        &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi} \neq T;\\
    \tsbar{\phi \rightarrow \psi} 
        &= T \text{ iff } \tsbar{\phi}\neq T \text{ or } \tsbar{\psi}=T;\\
    \tsbar{\forall x \phi} 
        &= T \text{ iff, for every } a\in D_s,\ \sbar{\phi}^{[v/a]} = T;\\
    \tsbar{\Box_> \phi} 
        &= T \text{ iff, for every } t > s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
    \tsbar{\Box_< \phi} 
        &= T \text{ iff, for every } t < s, \tsbar{\phi} = T.\\
    \intertext{(Later-than is given the obvious definition: $t > s =_{df} s < t$.)
        \smallskip\newline
        \hspace*{\parindent}
               Then, the defined operators:}
    \tsbar{\Box_\geq \phi}  
        & = T \text{ iff, for every } t \geq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
    \tsbar{\Box_\leq \phi}  
        & = T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s, \tsbar{\phi} = T;\\
    \tsbar{\Box \phi}       
        & = T \text{ iff, for every } t \leq s \vee s \leq t, \tsbar{\phi} = T.
        \end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This gets exactly what I want, thanks. As a side note, the `\mbox{}` is not necessary when `\hspace*{\parindent}` is used, but there might be some subtle difference I'm missing.

Comment: @Denis, you have right. It was forgetting there, since in the first I test with `\quad`. I will correct the answer.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of the `\smallskip` before `\newline`? I see it provides a little bit of extra spacing, does the article class typically put a little extra space between paragraphs as opposed to simply arbitrary new lines?

Comment: If you want a paragraph indentation simpler just to use `\endgraf` instead of `\newline` and none of the `\mbox` and `\hspace` weirdness

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for that! `\endgraf` is a new one for me!

Comment: @Dennis, I just overtaken it from your MWE. I assumed, that you like with it emulate `\parskip` between paragraphs, so I left it there. For exact emulation it should be replaced with `\vspace{\parskip}` (not yet tested,).

Comment: @Zarko Ah, I see.

Comment: Moving the acceptance to egreg's answer given his reply to my comment. Will add a bounty to express appreciation once the time limit passes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`\\` is defined for the alignment, but you can use `\newline`

```
\intertext{(The later-than relation on stages is given the obvious definition: $t > s =_{df} s < t$.)\newline
%
Then, the defined operators:}
```

(But you get a terrible line break with the text width in the MWE, just before the forced break)

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed.